# Ввод даты и времени с клавы

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Задача "На ввод вам дан файл состоящий из пар временных отметок, для каждой последовательной пары отметок вам нужно подсчитать абсолютную разницу во времени в секундах"

Вводные данные (берутся из .txt):

```
Sun 10 May 2021 13:54:36 -0700
Sun 10 May 2021 13:54:36 -0000
Sat 02 May 2021 19:54:36 +0530
Fri 01 May 2021 13:54:36 -0000
```

Не могу понять как сделать ввод конкретно этой даты

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не охота заморачиваться с маской для strptime то можно так.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

text = 'Sun 10 May 2021 13:54:36 -0700'

print(parse(text))
# 2021-05-10 13:54:36-07:00
print(repr(parse(text)))
# datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10, 13, 54, 36, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -25200)
```

Но если прям очень захочется то:

```py
from datetime import datetime

text = 'Sun 10 May 2021 13:54:36 -0700'

pattern = '%a %d %b %Y %X %z'

print(datetime.strptime(text, pattern))
print(repr(datetime.strptime(text, pattern)))

#2021-05-10 13:54:36-07:00
#datetime.datetime(2021, 5, 10, 13, 54, 36, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=61200)))
```

```py
# UPD
from datetime import datetime

pattern = '%a %d %b %Y %X %z'

with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(datetime.strptime(line.strip(), pattern))
#2021-05-10 13:54:36-07:00
#2021-05-10 13:54:36+00:00
#2021-05-02 19:54:36+05:30
#2021-05-01 13:54:36+00:0
```

```py
from datetime import datetime

pattern = '%a %d %b %Y %X %z'

with open('data.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    dates = [
        *map(
            lambda x: datetime.strptime(x.strip(), pattern),
            filter(lambda x: bool(x.strip()), file.readlines())
        )
    ]

for f, s in zip(dates[::2], dates[1::2]):
    print(abs(int(f.timestamp() - s.timestamp())))
```

## Datetime parsing patterns

| Directive | Meaning | Example | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `%a` | Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name. | Sun, Mon, …, Sat (en_US); So, Mo, …, Sa (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%A` | Weekday as locale’s full name. | Sunday, Monday, …, Saturday (en_US); Sonntag, Montag, …, Samstag (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%w` | Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. | 0, 1, …, 6 |  |
| `%d` | Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number. | 01, 02, …, 31 | (9) |
| `%b` | Month as locale’s abbreviated name. | Jan, Feb, …, Dec (en_US); Jan, Feb, …, Dez (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%B` | Month as locale’s full name. | January, February, …, December (en_US); Januar, Februar, …, Dezember (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%m` | Month as a zero-padded decimal number. | 01, 02, …, 12 | (9) |
| `%y` | Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 99 | (9) |
| `%Y` | Year with century as a decimal number. | 0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999 | (2) |
| `%H` | Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 23 | (9) |
| `%I` | Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number. | 01, 02, …, 12 | (9) |
| `%p` | Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. | AM, PM (en_US); am, pm (de_DE) | (1), (3) |
| `%M` | Minute as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 59 | (9) |
| `%S` | Second as a zero-padded decimal number. | 00, 01, …, 59 | (4), (9) |
| `%f` | Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left. | 000000, 000001, …, 999999 | (5) |
| `%z` | UTC offset in the form `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff]]` (empty string if the object is naive). | (empty), +0000, -0400, +1030, +063415, -030712.345216 | (6) |
| `%Z` | Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive). | (empty), UTC, GMT | (6) |
| `%j` | Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number. | 001, 002, …, 366 | (9) |
| `%U` | Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0. | 00, 01, …, 53 | (7), (9) |
| `%W` | Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0. | 00, 01, …, 53 | (7), (9) |
| `%c` | Locale’s appropriate date and time representation. | Tue Aug 16 21:30:00 1988 (en_US); Di 16 Aug 21:30:00 1988 (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%x` | Locale’s appropriate date representation. | 08/16/88 (None); 08/16/1988 (en_US); 16.08.1988 (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%X` | Locale’s appropriate time representation. | 21:30:00 (en_US); 21:30:00 (de_DE) | (1) |
| `%%` | A literal `'%'` character. | % |  |

Several additional directives not required by the C89 standard are included for convenience. These parameters all correspond to ISO 8601 date values.

| Directive | Meaning | Example | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `%G` | ISO 8601 year with century representing the year that contains the greater part of the ISO week (`%V`). | 0001, 0002, …, 2013, 2014, …, 9998, 9999 | (8) |
| `%g` | ISO 8601 year without century as a zero-padded decimal number representing the year that contains the greater part of the ISO week (`%V`). | 01, 02, ..., 13, 14, ..., 98, 99 |  |
| `%u` | ISO 8601 weekday as a decimal number where 1 is Monday. | 1, 2, …, 7 |  |
| `%V` | ISO 8601 week as a decimal number with Monday as the first day of the week. Week 01 is the week containing Jan 4. | 01, 02, …, 53 | (8), (9) |

Comment: Так, еще вопрос
Как с .txt файла прочитать все строки и записать в переменные?
я использую
 f = open("date.txt", "r")
for line in f:
    print(line)
f.close()

Comment: @БумерСолнечный, А можно пример как данные в файле выглядат?

Comment: 4 строки, как в шапке темы выкладывал (даты)

Comment: @БумерСолнечный, добавил

Comment: спасибо за готовую задачу, сижу пока разбираюсь почему так

Comment: второй результат должен быть: 88200

Comment: и я не могу понять почему у Вас выдает 1800

Comment: @БумерСолнечный поправил

Comment: первый вариант ответа 25200 верный, а второй ответ 1800 не верный и я думаю мб преподаватель не правильно выход рассчитал

Comment: Вывод:
25200
88200

Comment: @БумерСолнечный, С решением не заладилось. Убрал решение, чуть позже посмотрю

Comment: В любом случае спасибо огромное, хоть момент понял с этой задачей, сижу думаю дальше

Comment: @БумерСолнечный, нашел ошибку. Обновил

Comment: Исправно, а в чем была ошибка?